# Filter array with first and last letter optimization

Tags: arrays, swift, character

I have a an array of strings and I want to get all the occurrences that start with a certain character and end with a certain character. Here is how I have done it today:

```
var arr = ["Aa", "Bb", "Ab", "Abc", "Dd"]
var newArr = [String]()

for str in arr {
    if str.characters.first == "A" && str.characters.last == "c" {
        newArr.append(str)
    }
}
arr = newArr
```

If feels really messy, but it works. Can I optimize this using filter or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` with `hasPrefix` and `hasSuffix`. Try this:

```
arr = arr.filter({ $0.hasPrefix("A") && $0.hasSuffix("c") }) // Abc
```